# apt errors not installing

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, aws, amazon-ec2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently trying to install `mysql-server` using `sudo apt install mysql-server` on my Ubuntu 20.04 WSL. However, after entering `Y` to install, I am hitting the following error:

```
Setting up ec2-instance-connect (1.1.12+dfsg1-0ubuntu3.20.04.1) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
sshd override added, restarting daemon
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package ec2-instance-connect (--configure):
 installed ec2-instance-connect package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ec2-instance-connect
```

This output also appears when running other `apt` or `apt-get` commands. How can I fix this error (very new using Linux).

Comment: I noticed one other step you may want to take after you accepted the answer.  `ec2-instance-connect` also adds a user that would normally be deleted by the postremove script.  See my updated answer to remove it.  If you upvote *this* comment, it should act as a flag for me to come back and remove it (since I'll assume you've seen it).  That's probably better than flagging it for a (much overloaded) moderator to remove.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any idea where the `ec2-instance-connect` came from?  That looks like it was already installed before you attempted to install MySQL Server, and it just shouldn't be there on anything but an Ubuntu instance running on Amazon EC2.

You likely *have* already installed MySQL Server correctly on a previous attempt, but now `apt` is attempting to configure the `ec2-instance-connect` package each time you run it.

The answer *should* be simple -- Remove the `ec2-instance-connect` package.  Unfortunately that package's post-remove script assumes that Systemd is available, which it isn't under WSL.

So you'll need to:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/ec2-instance-connect.postrm
sudo apt purge ec2-instance-connect
sudo deluser --system --quiet ec2-instance-connect
```

`apt` should be working properly again after this.

While you probably aren't using `sshd` under WSL (it's a hassle, and not even necessary for remote connection except in rare cases), you may also want to scan your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  The package installation also seems to make modifications to that file in some situations, but I haven't fully grokked it to be able to tell what they might be.

It's *possible* that there's some other cruft still hanging around, since the post-remove script attempts to run  `deb-systemd-helper purge ec2-instance-connect` (and can't).  But I'm not sure what that attempts to do.  It's probably harmless to leave the cruft around.